# Proper siunitx way of typesetting complex expressions

Tags: siunitx, typography

What is the proper `siunitx` way of typesetting complex expressions such as `$(56\pi + 8\pi\sqrt{5}) cm^2$`? I have been trying with `\SI{}{}` and `\qty{}{}` but it always complains on `\pi`.

EDIT: Additional question, how about the proper way of typesetting `$a$ cm`?

Comment: You need to tell it that `\pi` should be seen as an input, look up `input-digits` in the manual.

Comment: In v3 of the manual in section 8.11 `\pi` is used as an example

Comment: Ahh, well then  you get into trouble with `\sqrt{5}`, which is fixed by setting `parse-numbers=false`

Comment: @JosephWright was already typing it. Is where a way to ask it to put `()` on the number part or is that manual?

Comment: @daleif There's no automated addition of `()` as the number is not parsed: the whole point is it's a 'black box'

Comment: As for the extra question, did you try it with `parse-numbers=false`? `\qty{a}{\cm}` probably works (untested)

Comment: @daleif It did not help. I have tried all these: \qty{a}{\cm} \qty{$a$}{\cm} $\qty{a}{\cm}$ \SI{a}{\cm} \SI{$a$}{\cm} $\SI{a}{\cm}$ \SI[parse-numbers=false]{a}{\cm} \SI[parse-numbers=false]{$a$}{\cm} $\SI[parse-numbers=false]{a}{\cm}$. Have in mind I need somewhat "old" solution as I need to typeset things with Overleaf (Package: siunitx 2020/02/25 v2.8b A comprehensive (SI) units package).

Comment: I'm not sure what the bounty is after here: dalief is a pretty good source (he and I know each other well, I have no issue with his answer, ...).

Comment: @JosephWright Please check my previous comment here, I have tried many different typesettings but none of them suffice ("a in math mode + the unit").

Comment: @ivankokan Using exactly dalief's set up, `\qty{a}{\cm\squared}` or `\qty{a}{cm^{2}}` work fine. If that is not working for you, I think a separate, linked, question showing exactly your input and output is best.

Comment: @ivankokan If you are using v2, you want `\SI` rather than `\qty`

Comment: @JosephWright None of those produce `a` in math-mode, what I asked about.

Comment: @ivankokan Please ask a new question showing your input: `\qty[parse-numbers = false]{a}{\cm}` (v3)/`\SI[parse-numbers = false]{a}{\cm}` (v2 and v3) _does_ use math mode for the `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably need to switch of number parsing. This seems to work (assuming siunitx v3)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  parse-numbers=false,
}
    
\begin{document}
$\qty{(56\pi+8\pi\sqrt{5})}{\cm\squared}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `\squared`?

Comment: That is the proper way with `siunitx`. `^2` does work, but `\squared` etc are better to use with units as then `per-mode` (don't remember if it has been renamed in v3) can handle special fractions etc. `\qty[per-mode=fraction]{1}{\kg\per\cm\squared}` works, `\qty[per-mode=fraction]{1}{\kg\per\cm^2}` does not

Comment: @ivankokan You can use 'literal' units (so just `cm^{2}`), but you loose out on any unit auto-manipulation

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! Please check the edit in the original post.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126795/discussion-on-answer-by-daleif-proper-siunitx-way-of-typesetting-complex-expre).

Answer (score -1):

This works (siunitx 3.0.10):

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$(56\pi + 8\pi\sqrt{5}) cm^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: after @ivankokan's comment:
See answer from daleif.

Comment: probably becasue it is not even using `siunitx` (NB: I did not give the `-1` but I agree that this is not a proper answer)

Comment: Well, I don't care who -1'd me. I thought the issue was that \pi was giving the OP an error, but it does not in my mwe.

Comment: I gave -1 because cm^2 is not typeset properly.

Comment: @ivankokan it is good practice to explain in a comment why one gave a `-1`, the user does not always know what they did wrong.